# Absolute positioning in relation to a input[type=range] - Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a range slider, and with the help of Stackoverflow the tool-tip follows the slider almost correctly. The issue i'm running into is that the tool-tip is not always centered above the sliders-thumb. Especially when you move the slider left from the right side.

https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/gWYBWb

I've researched the heck out of this, and i think it's related to the offset position. Does anybody have experience with this?

```
// Tool Tip
$(document).mousemove(function(e){   
    if(moveit){
            var parentOffset = $('#range-slider').parent().offset(); 
            var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            var step = $('#range-slider').width()/5; 
            valS = $('#range-slider').val();
            if(val != valS){
              val = $('#range-slider').val();
              console.log(val);
              console.log(step * val);
              var xxx = relX + step;
              console.log(relY);
              console.log(relX);
            }
            //console.log(relX);
            $('#sliderPrice').css('top', parentOffset.top-350).css('left',xxx-120);
            //console.log($("#range-slider").val());
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your Tool Tip move function. You no longer need the `step` variable and I've created a new variable, `offsetLeft` in place of `xxx`.

There's a new `if` statement that will check if `valS` is less than or equal to `val` if it is, we add back the offset of the tool tip's width.

Also, we'll only be moving the tool tip if the two values don't match as well as updating the `val` variable.

Hope this helps!

#### Edit

You'll also notice the new `.css()` function call is using an object rather than calling `.css()` again.

```js
// Tool Tip
$(document).mousemove(function(e){   
    if(moveit){
            var parentOffset = $('#range-slider').parent().offset(); 
            var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            var step = $('#range-slider').width()/5;
            var leftOffset = (relX - 120);
            valS = $('#range-slider').val();
            if(val != valS){
              if ( valS >= val ) {
                leftOffset += 120;
              }
              val = $('#range-slider').val();
              $('#sliderPrice').css({
                'top': parentOffset.top-350,
                'left': leftOffset
              });
            }
            //console.log(relX);
            //$('#sliderPrice').css('top', parentOffset.top-350).css('left',leftOffset);
            //console.log($("#range-slider").val());
    }
  });
```

Comment: That's great! Do you know why it's bouncing from the left to the right side of the slider thumb? Is there any way to center it?

Comment: @StinkyTofu I think it has to do with when you start to drag the `relX` position is always changing but we're assigning the `left` property when `valS != val`. If you `console.log(relX)`, IIRC from last night, the value snaps weirdly causing the minor hiccup with it not being perfectly centered.